# Drop a browser support and show an html page with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to figure out how you can drop a browser support. let's say for example IE11, how to do this with webpack and prevent it from bundling code since it will break anyway. And show a UI for that browser (browser unsupported...). I came across browserlist and I know it's for browser selection, but can't find a workaround using it.

Let's say I have some utility function isIE11 that detects the browser, and want to do something like this:

```
{
  entry: isIE11 ? 'index.ie11.js' : 'index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'My App',
      template: isIE11 ? 'src/ie11.index.html.hbs' : 'src/index.html.hbs'
      filename: 'assets/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

Even tho there is no module needed when showing this simple UI in ie11

Answer (score 2):

That plugin will be run when you compile... so at that point there is no browser.

One thing you could do maybe is compile it without ie11 support (in the babel config?)... and then in the html page, put a separate script in a script tag at the top that checks for unsupported browsers, and then either redirects you, or just replaces the current page with the message:

```
<script>
if (... code to check browser) {
  window.location = "ie11.index.html";
}
// and then you have to deploy the ie11 index page
</script>
```

or if it is a short message

```
<script>
if (... code to check browser) {
  document.getObjectById('main-div').innerHTML = 'Welcome to the ie version';
} else {
  // do what you normally do - put the real content into `main-div`
}
</script>
```